# не работает оператор goto так как надо в языке СИ

Tags: c, goto, тернарный-оператор

Не пойму в чем проблема: goto отказывается работать, ошибка типа:

> error: Expected an expression

```
start:printf("Введите один из вариантов: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &point);

point==1?write(path()):point==2?read(path()):point==3?incode(path()):point==4?decode(path()):point==5?exit(1):goto start;

//если вставить сюда после тернарного оператора: goto start; - то все отрабатывает
```

Comment: Два варианта: 1 -  не использовать `goto` вообще, никогда. 2 - если сильно хочется - то сделать через `if`. Через тернарный оператор так как вы хотите сделать не получится.

Comment: А если человек введет значение 6? Бесконечный goto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`goto` в языке C - это statement, а не operator. Его невозможно использовать внутри выражений, также как невозможно использовать внутри выражений такие statement как `if`, `while` или `return`.

(В русскоязычных источниках термин *оператор* часто используется в двух несвязанных значениях: *operator* и *statement*, что к сожалению нередко приводит к путанице).

Comment: Термин "оператор" путают только в каких-то малограмотных публикациях. Английское слово "statement" часто переводят как "инструкция". А вообще есть смысл добавить оба этих термина в [наш словарь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1268).

Answer (score 2):

Если вам так уж нужно использовать `goto` изнутри выражения, то придется *эмулировать* этот оператор с помощью пары функций [setjmp/longjmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html).

Просто шутки ради

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  jmp_buf e;
  int i = 0;

  setjmp(e);
  // start:  // эмулируем преход сюда
  puts("before while");
  while (i < 10) 
    av[1] ? (puts(av[1]), ++i) : (puts(av[0]), ++i, longjmp(e, i), i);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: Однако согласно спецификации `setjmp`/`longjmp`, не-volatile локальные переменные той функции, которая делала `setjmp`, которые поменялись между моментом `setjmp` и моментом `longjmp`, будут содержать *непредсказуемые значения* после выполнения `longjmp`. У вас `i` - как раз такая переменная. То есть после возвращения на `setjmp` вам никто не гарантирует, что `i` сохранит свое последнее значение.

Comment: @AnT, согласен, с оптимизацией (когда `i` в регистре) работать не будет. Все же мой ответ это не руководство по программированию безобразий, а иллюстрация принципиальных возможностей (скорее всего gcc/linux, хотя и в других системах наверное тоже можно такое сделать)

Comment: Вопреки названию, функции `setjmp()` и `longjmp()` ничего общего с `goto` не имеют. Цели и реализация совершенно разные.

Comment: @0andriy, сильное замечание (особенно если погуглить устоявшееся выражение "нелокальный goto"). Насчет реализации еще можно согласиться (больше похоже на реализацию сопрограммы (или наоборот? -)), ну а вот цель, обычно та же самая (конечно, конкретно ваших целей не знаю) -- продолжить исполнение с заданной  точки кода.

Comment: @avp, просто кто-то знает чуть больше, чем русскоязычный интернет ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685406/practical-usage-of-setjmp-and-longjmp-in-c

Comment: @0andriy, насколько я понимаю, в вашей ссылке речь о другом (что применение в программе  longjmp обычно не красиво (может приводить к ряду трудно отлавливаемых ошибок)). А тут обсуждалось, как сделать `goto` *из выражения*. И я в ответе  просто показал принципиальную возможность такой передачи управления (совершенно не советуя так программировать на практике (там же написано -- "*шутки ради*"))